# Удалить страницу на которой стоит редирект

Tags: seo

Может кто подскажет, как сделать правильно

Есть две страницы:
страница 1 и страница 2

Нужно было со страницы 2 перенести контент на страницу 1 и затем удалить страницу 2
Я перенес контент со страницы 2 на 1 и настроил 301 редирект с 2 на 1.

Вопрос следующий. Если я в вебмастере добавлю запрос на удаление страницы 2, поисковик не удалит страницу 1? Так как на нее стоит редирект

Answer (score 0):

Лучше убрать удаление в вебмастере. Дождитесь переиндексации, гугл сам удалит ее с индекса.

Comment: Не понимаю, что значит "убрать удаление". Это удалить или не удалять?

Comment: Если вы поставили в вебмастере запрос на удаление, его убрать.